# error al ejecutar npm start

Tags: nodejs, npm, packages

cuando escribo el comando npm start para iniciar mi proyecto me muestra el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así tengo mi archivo package.json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cabe anotar que el día de ayer corrí el instalador mas reciente de nodejs en mi pc windows 10. Antes de eso se ejecutaba sin problemas.

Agradezco su ayuda chicos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno luego de buscar por internet y probar la solucion fue simple:

Simplemente debia correr el comando npm start dentro de toda la ruta del proyecto. incluido la carpeta que lleva por nombre cliente:

PS D:\CARLOS\CURSOS DESARROLLO SOFTWARE\CURSO REACT (Juan de la Torre)\MERNStack\cliente>npm start

Comment: ejecuto el comando desde la carpeta donde tengo el proyecto, no resuelve el problema.